# Calling a service as text is typed in a combobox

Tags: angular, combobox, kendo-ui

First of all, I am not an Angular Developer, I am a DBA trying to learn some code :)

I have a form in which there is a combobox (Kendo UI).
This combobox should display some suggestions as I type.
These suggestions come from a service and the service shouldn't be called if the string in the combobox is not at least 4 characters long.

I am pretty much there I believe but I fail with the syntax and how to implement the `pipe`, 
 `debounceTime` and the `filter`...

I have a [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oscaax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) but the code inside the function `getRegistrationList` is probably totally incorrect and faulty... Please be indulgent. I know that I need to get some more basic knowledge and I am absolutely willing to learn. But I am in a kind of emergency here so thank you in advance for your help.

The component looks like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { AutoCompleteComponent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime, switchMap, tap, filter } from "rxjs/operators";

import { DataService } from "./data.service";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `

   <form [formGroup]="flightNoticeForm">

            <kendo-combobox
              style="min-width: 20em"
              #registrationbox
              floatingLabel="First Name"
              [data]="data"
              [filterable]="true"
              [textField]="'text'"
              [valueField]="'value'"
              [placeholder]="'First name (eg. Tom)'"
              (filterChange)="getRegistrationList($event)"
              (valueChange)="getRegistrationValues($event.value)"
            >
            </kendo-combobox>

    </form>
    <pre>
      {{ registrationbox.value | json }}
    </pre>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
 public flightNoticeForm: FormGroup;
  public data: any[];
  public scope: string = 'registration';
  public arrival: AutoCompleteComponent;

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.flightNoticeForm = this.fb.group({
        registration: new FormControl({ value: '', text: '' })
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {}


  getRegistrationList(event) {

    console.log('getRegistrationList CALLED : ' + event);

    this.registrationbox.pipe(
        tap(() => {
          this.data = [];
          this.registrationbox.toggle(false);
        }),
        filter((v: string) => v.length >= 3),
        debounceTime(500),
        switchMap((x: string) => this.dataService.getData(x.toLocaleLowerCase()))
      )
      .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        console.log("Autocomplete : " + JSON.stringify(data));
        this.data = data;
        this.registrationbox.toggle(true);
      });


  }

  getRegistrationValues(event) {
    console.log('setAcfRegistration CALLED : ' + event);
  }
}
```

And the service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class DataService {
  constructor() {}

  getData(term: string): Observable<any[]> {
    console.log("server call...");
    return of(data).pipe(
      map(data =>
        data.filter(item => item.text.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(term))
      )
    );
  }
}

const data: Array<{ value: string; text: string }> = [
  {
    value: "1",
    text: "Sam"
  },
  { value: "2", text: "Tom" },
  {
    value: "3",
    text: "John"
  },
  {
    value: "4",
    text: "Aaron"
  },
  {
    value: "5",
    text: "Peter"
  },
  {
    value: "6",
    text: "Nathalie"
  },
  {
    value: "7",
    text: "Rachel"
  },
  { value: "8", text: "David" },
  {
    value: "9",
    text: "Joseph"
  },
  {
    value: "10",
    text: "Lucille"
  },
  {
    value: "11",
    text: "Rose"
  },
  {
    value: "12",
    text: "Alice"
  },
  {
    value: "13",
    text: "Isaac"
  },
  { value: "14", text: "Albert" },
  { value: "15", text: "Chris" }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use something as simple as that in getRegistrationList function:

```
 getRegistrationList(event) {
console.log('getRegistrationList CALLED : ' + event);
if(event.length>2){
this.dataService.getData(event).subscribe(data=>{
  this.data=data;
})
}}
```

Comment: That is a very good start and it solves the sting length issue. Thank you very much!
I still need to implement the part of code that is in the `pipe`. The part involving the `toggle`is important for the combobox behavior.